# Rails link_to params .id instead of /id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having a small problem creating a link.

My view:

```
<%= link_to 'slet', blog_comments_path(c.blog, c), :confirm => 'Er du sikker?', :method => :delete %>
```

Output:

```
http://localhost:3000/blogs/5/comments.6
```

Where it should by:

```
http://localhost:3000/blogs/5/comments/6
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`blog_comments_path` is the route for all comments for a blog. if you want just a comment, you have to use `blog_comment_path` (check with `rake routes`, I *might* be wrong with the syntax. But you get the idea.)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, because in my routes I had

```
resource :products
```

and not

```
resources :products
```

Don't forget the plural ;)

And always check your routes :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this shorter syntax would work :

```
<%= link_to 'slet', [c.blog, c], :confirm => 'Er du sikker?', :method => :delete %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had urls like `users.1` when I wanted `users/1`
I had to add the line:
`resources :users`
to my routes.rb file